# Boto3 / ECR-Public errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecr-public

I'm trying to use the `ecr-public` client but I get similar errors when I execute any method.

```
import boto3
client=boto3.client('ecr-public')
client.get_authorization_token()
```

error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation (reached max retries: 4):

```
client.create_repository(repositoryName="test-project")
```

error: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the CreateRepository operation (reached max retries: 4):

My user has full AWS admin permissions and if I change from client type `ecr-public` to `ecr`, it works.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using `us-east-1` region?

Comment: I'm using us-west-2

Comment: You must be using `us-east-1`. Only this region supports public ecr. Can you run the command with `client=boto3.client('ecr-public', region_name='us-east-1')`.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind, I will make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

`ecr-public` can only be used in `us-east-1` region. Thus you have to set your `client` for that region:

```
client=boto3.client('ecr-public', region_name='us-east-1')
```